# Add an element into a bidimensional array in perl

Tags: perl

My question is basically a technical question;

If I want to add an element into a bidimensional array I do:

`$array[$i][$#{$a[$i]}+1]=$new_scalar_to_add;`

is it a correct way

I now that usually for the one dimensional array is possible to add an element into an array by mean of `push` as

`push(@array, $new_scalar_to_add);`

My question is, there is a better way to add elements into an array or the two methods are equivalent?

Comment: Those two statements are not equivalent. One assigns a scalar to a two-dimensional array, the other adds a scalar to a one-dimensional array. If you are looking for preference, usually I'd say stick with `push` or `unshift` unless those cannot be used for what you have in mind.

Comment: I changed the `$array[$i][$#{$a[$i]}]=$new_scalar_to_add;` into `$array[$i][$#{$a[$i]}+1]=$new_scalar_to_add;`

Comment: Yes, but what is the array `@a`? That's not in your code. I suppose you meant `$#{$array[$i]}`. Still, a very clunky solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what's wrong with push?

```
perl -MData::Dumper -E'
   @arr = ([1,2,3],[6,5,4],[7,8,9]);
   push @{ $arr[$_] }, int rand 9 for (0..$#arr);
   say Dumper \@arr;
'
```

Your method will not work, because `$#array` means "the number of array's last element", you not adding new element, you just redefine the last element.

```
 perl -MData::Dumper -E'
    @arr = ([1,2,3],[6,5,4],[7,8,9]);
    $arr[1][$#arr] = 777;
    say Dumper \@arr;
 '
```

If you want to add it, you need to use `$#array+1` or `scalar @array` syntax. Better use `push`.

Comment: I just wanted to know if "my" method is correct aswell, if there could be any problems that I didn t think about...

Comment: Yes sorry, I made a mystake, I wanted to write `$#array+1`, otherwise I would not add anything. Anyway my question is, why `push` is better?

Comment: `push $arr[$_], $x` is highly experimental, doesn't work with all arrays, won't work unless `$arr[$_]` already contains an array ref, and isn't backwards compatible. Use `push @{ $arr[$_] }, $x` instead. Fixed.